# Jenkins 2.3.5 Build Notification (Emailext, bitbucket build status notifier) Not Working

Tags: jenkins, bcbsn

We recently rebuilt our Jenkins server and we are using Jenkins 2.3.5/JDK8/ubuntu 14.04/bitbucket cloud/hipchat cloud.

After we got the newly built Jenkins server running, everything worked except for the build result notification.

We used to get the bitbucket account that we used with Jenkins to comment on the build result, so we can receive it in the hipchat room, even without using hipchat notification plugin. Now, we have tried the emailext plugin, Bitbucket Build Status Notifier Plugin, but none of them worked. It seems that the plugin is all out of date in terms of configurations.

For emailext, it complains "An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored." But we put a number of email in the "Default Recipients". And all the SMTP settings are correct since we can receive testing message.

For Bitbucket Build Status Notifier Plugin, I followed [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-build-status-notifier-plugin), but I couldn't find the "Bitbucket notify build status" in the job configure.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Extended Email notification plugin, set SMTP server in Jenkins global configuration